# Google Places API - Place Picker - Center screen after search

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm currently using Google's Place Picker in my Android app, everything is working fine, except for one detail. While searching for a place, when I pick one of them it returns to the map but it doesn't center the map in the place I've just selected. Is there a way to do that?

I'm using the following code to launch the Place Picker map.

```
// Start Google Place Picker
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
try {
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQ_CODE);
} 
catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes it is.. just wait i m posting my answer here..